# What version of Java is needed for zxing 1.7?

Tags: java-me, zxing

I am developing a barcode scanning application for J2ME. For that, I have come to know that zxing 1.7 has to be used. What version of Java do I need for zxing 1.7?

Comment: I'll edit your question but you should take time to write a grammatical, formatted, complete question next time.

Answer (score 0):

1.7 was the last version that supported JavaME, yes. Because of that, it requires only Java 1.2. I think it required CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.0.